# How do I update existing Azure Vm scale set using Arm template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I need to add a new extension to existing VM scale set via ARM template.

The existing VM scale set is created using ARM template.

So I am planning to add the new extension in the template and run the template using New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment powershell function

But the update is failing with error

```
 '{
  "error": {
    "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
    "message": "Changing property 'adminPassword' is not allowed.",
    "target": "adminPassword"
  }
```

Does the arm template provides a way to update existing VM scale set ?
Can I conditional avoid  "osProfile" update which defines admin password? 
I don't want to change the  "osProfile" while updating the VM scale set

Comment: i think you can just amend it from the template, I mean `osProfile`

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: just remove it from the template and it should work

Comment: Can you post both the original template and the new one?